# How can I use Android as a remote control for streaming?

Tags: vlc-media-player, android

I would like to know if I can use Android to remote control streaming on my laptop?
I would like to use my laptop as my streaming server and use my HDTV to view the stream.

And I need some way to remote control my streaming server.

I have read about
http://maketecheasier.com/install-vlc-shares-in-Ubuntu-and-stream-videos-to-Android/2011/02/25
and 
http://code.google.com/p/android-vlc-remote/

but those are streaming to Android phone itself.

I am just need something to remote control streaming to my TV.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android-vlc-remote project allows for controlling VLC via it's HTTP interface.  You don't specify what you host OS is running, but on my WinXP system all I did was the following:

- Start VLC on PC
- Go to View -> Add Interface -> Web Interface
- Start VLC Remote on Android
- Add IP address of PC

That's it!  After that I could hit the little "Eject" icon to bring up a file browser that showed me the PC's files and selected something to play.  The file played on the PC.

Otherwise, just use the HTTP interface itself from your Android to control VNC, once you've enabled the HTTP interface in VLC itself.  You can use the phone's built-in browser for that.

Comment: I think the solutions he linked to just for streaming to an Android device, not controlling streams to other devices.

Comment: @typoknig: No, the android-vlc-remote project is for controlling an instance of VLC running on another system.  I just tested it with my phone.  Going to edit my answer for clarification.

Comment: Awesome. I think I'll try it this weekend with my phone too!

Comment: android-vlc-remote project, can i control an instance of VLC stream a media to my HDTV ?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit heavy, but you could install a VNC viewer on your Android phone and remote into your laptop and control the stream that way, but @afrazier said he confirmed the links you posted actually do what you want them to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think [SSHmote](http://www.zokama.com/sshmote) does what you want. It's an Android app that controls different kinds of media players. However it will only work if you're on Linux/BSD.

> SSHmote is a remote control for Android devices that uses the SSH
>   protocol to connect to your computer and control your favorite
>   multimedia applications through editable profiles. Using the SSH
>   protocol means that for most Linux/BSD distributions, no additional
>   server installation will be requiered, you will just have to enter
>   your username and password in SSHmote and it will turn your Android
>   device into a cool remote control.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more task specific remote...

XBMC has an Android remote available:
http://xbmc.org/freezy3k/2010/07/13/official-xbmc-remote-for-android/

So does Winamp somewhere.

Doubtless there are other media players with Android remotes. Google is your friend.